# Can i answer a closed question?

Tags: support, answers, closed-questions

Can I answer a closed question?

If yes, then how?

Because I am not able to answer it. I'm not sure if the Stack Exchange community allows this or not.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't answer a closed question. From the Help Center article ["What does it mean if a question is "closed"?"](/help/closed-questions):

> Closed questions cannot be answered, but can be edited to make them eligible for reopening.

You can try to edit the question so that it's a good fit for the community; if you do this within 5 days of the closure, the edit will push the question into the Reopen Votes review queue and other community members can decide whether to reopen the question or not.